# How to load a page without reloading it in protractor

Tags: protractor

While doing e2e testing using protractor ,a requirement comes to load a page.I tried `browser.get`,But that reloads the page resulting in cache clear.Getting ERROR as

Failed: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

**How to load a page without reloading it in protractor?**

Answer (score 10):

If you question is about routing in an angular app, then you can try with `browser.setLocation()`.

```
browser.get('http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial');
browser.setLocation('api');
// You now will be in http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api without any page reload
```

Reference: [Protractor API browser.setLocation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.setLocation)

Answer (score 2):

Protractor's `browser.get` will always navigate to a `RESET_URL=data:text/html, <html></html>` before navigating to the page you requested. There are a couple options to get around this:

`browser.driver.get(url)` will use the webdriver native command, and bypass protractor's reset url. If you go this route on an angular page, you will want to add in a `waitForAngular()` before the command so that you wait for the original page to settle before navigating to the new page.

`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` in your test will essentially turn `browser.get` into `browser.driver.get` and bypass the reset url. The downside here is that your entire test would now be ignoring angular synchronization.

Source: protractor/lib/protractor.js